# Add scopes to authentified oAuth2 user

Tags: symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using HWIOAuthBundle to authenticate users with their Google account.

I would like to know how to add scopes after user's logged in.

eg: According to his parameters, I would like to manage user's Google Calendar. It should ask new authorization from Google for me to access this scope.

So the question is, how can I ask for new authorizations to my logged in user ?

Answer (score 0):

HWIOAuthBundle requests only "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" scope by default. In order to manage user's Google Calendar, you want to request "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" scope too.

Check this out on how to customize the scope you request:
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/resource_owners/google.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not in declaring scopes to be used for the session, but adding scope to an active session